# Can I merge multiple disc with installers/autorun into one disc?

Tags: iso-image, installer, autorun, disc

I have several small CD's and two of them have a installer and auto run enabled. I know how to create an ISO from disc (imgburn) but how can I can put them on a single disc without corrupting the installer?

Note: Its just a compilation of applications such as printer, drivers, webcam etc for my mom thus why I dont just put D-Tools and ISO's on the disc.

Answer (score 2):

The only conflict I can potentially see is the "autorun.inf" file, this is the file that tells the computer what file it should launch automatically. If your not worried about having to manually launching the installers, I can't see any reason why you can't just put installers in separate folders on the CD and delete the conflicting "autorun.inf" files.

Comment: And. . . if you think about it, many of the driver/software packages you DL from the manufacture (instead of the cd) would make creating a multi disk easier than the original CDs. It would be little different than having them on the hard drive in that situation. For the other more complex scripting junk and auto-run a "normal" user might be better off juggling disks than having a single script error from a compilation.

Comment: Majority of the installers will more than happily install from a folder (just make a note of what file to run if there's no setup.exe from the autorun.inf - you may find it's not on the root of the CD)